# How to send a parameter to AsyncCompletedEventArgs

Tags: events, asynchronous, c#-3.0

I have to pass `mobilId` (int) to the method `UpdateStatus`, I am not sure how to do that

```
Update_Completed += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(UpdateStatus);

protected void UpdateStatus(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, int mobilId)
{
    Define(Id, e.Cancelled, e.Error, mobilId);
}
```

Both these methods are in the same file. 
Kindly let me know if there'a any way to do it.

Comment: is this inheriting from a base class?  There has to be something that you start in order to have it finish.  Your update status method is a callback.

Answer (score 0):

What does the initial call look like?  There is a UserState option you should be able to set on the first method call.  It is of type object so it can be anything.

Comment: This is the method which is getting called on some condition :
private void updateAdd(string phoneNumber, int Id)
        {
Over here the call is made 
Update_Completed += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(UpdateStatus);
}

Comment: you call updateAdd, but unless you do anything else (such as this.update(userState)) the event will never fire.  Is there any code after update completed?

Comment: mobilId = UpdateDetails(Id, Rank,rankFkid, positionId,DtId);
Update_Completed += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(UpdateStatus);

Comment: Ok.  So.  what is inside this UpdateDetails method then?  If inside UpdateDetails you are making the start of the async call, then this will never fire because you are attaching the event after the call.  Sorry, to ask so many questions but there isn't enough information yet to give you a complete answer.

Comment: `private int UpdateDetails(Id, Rank,rankFkid, positionId,DtId)
        {
DomainB domainb = UpdateDomain(Id, Rank,rankFkid, positionId,DtId);

                DtId= UpdateInfo(domain);
                return DtId;
            
        }
`
My sincere apologies, as I am bit new to all this and didn't provide you with complete info.

Comment: `
 public void UpdateAddress(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                some code....
            }
            Update_Completed(this, e);
        }
`